# How to change text input to select input in chtml?

Tags: asp.net

I have a text form

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Flight</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FlyDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="FlyDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FlyDate" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FlyFrom" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="FlyFrom" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FlyFrom" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FlyTo" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="FlyTo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FlyTo" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to change `FlyFrom` and `FlyTo` to select options where users can select cites name (Tokyo, Osaka...). Currently they are text field. How can I do it?

Comment: If you change them from text-field to select how you will be populating them?

Answer (score 0):

```
There are two ways to populate based on your requirement. 

If values are constant you can directly hard code two drop downs.
<select>
    <option>State1</option>
    <option>State1</option>
</select>
if values are coming from DB you can fill those to values ViewBag object on index method

ViewBag.FromState=<<your list of states>>
ViewBag.ToDate==<your list of states>>

.cshtml 

@Html.DropDownList("FromState",ViewBag.FromStaes)
```